# Invalid CSRF Token 'null'

Tags: spring-boot, jbpm

I referred "https://github.com/mswiderski/jbpm-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-jbpm it runs well for GET request.
Now I am trying following code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestBody String emp){
    System.out.println("Your request is "+emp);
    return " Hi ";
}
```

through POSTMAN but it gives me error as,

{
    "timestamp": 1511946868300,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    **"message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.",**
    "path": "/test"
}

Please anyone help me to come out of it.

Comment: Did you have any config like security config class ?

Comment: Yes,I do have SpringSecurityIdentityProvider java class which implements IdentityProvider interface.This is link from where I referred code https://github.com/mswiderski/jbpm-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-jbpm

Comment: I mean do you have any `HttpConfig`?

Comment: No I don't have HttpConfig

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and below trick works for me.
Set **http.csrf().disable()**  inside configure method of your **DefaultWebSecurityConfig** Class.

Please refer https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.12.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/ [ **3.4.1.2. Configure authentication and authorization**].

Hope this solution help you.